# Programmatically add Panorama Items

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml, c#-4.0, panorama-control

I am working on windows Phone 7.5 App and I want to display a list of images programmatically in panorama control.I have the xaml

```
 <!--Panorama item three-->
 <controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="DiaPanorama" Header="History" FontSize="20">
```

and the code part is  -

```
 PanoramaItem p = new PanoramaItem();
 Image i = new Image();
 i.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/web.png", UriKind.Relative));
 p.Margin = new Thickness(0, -10, 0, -2);

 p.Content = i;
 DiaPanorama.Items.Add(p);
```

but it's showing an error that Microsoft.Phone.Control.PanoramaItem does not contain defination for Items. 
How can i solve this problem?Please help.
Is there any other approach for adding images programmatically in panorama?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When adding multiple items to a `PanoramaItem` or `PivotItem`, you must add a containing element first such as a `Grid`, `StackPanel` or `Canvas`

**In XAML**

```
<controls:Panorama x:Name="Panorama" Title="Panorama Control">
    <controls:PanoramaItem x:Name="Item1" Header="Item 1">
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock Text="Hello World" />
            <Image Source="Background.png" />
        </StackPanel>
    </controls:PanoramaItem>
</controls:Panorama>
```

**In C#**

```
var item = new PanoramaItem();
var panel = new StackPanel();

var text = new TextBlock();
text.Text = "HelloWorld";
panel.Children.Add(text);

var image = new Image();
image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("Background.png", UriKind.Relative));
panel.Children.Add(image);

item.Content = panel;
Panorama.Items.Add(item); // Add to existing panorama control
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your sample, you're trying to add a new PanoramaItem to an existing PanoramaItem. That won't work - you'd need to add the new PanoramaItem to the parent controls:Panorama object.

Comment: Could you please give me code snippet to add dynamically image in existing panorama page.

Comment: Deeko is saying that 'DiaPanorama' needs to be of type 'Panorama' not 'PanormaItem'